# Jar File not running in Windows Platform

Tags: java, windows, jar

I have a Java Project which runs fine in Netbeans IDE 8.0. But making a Runnable  JAR out of it  is not running in Windows platform. 
Processor: Core i3 
Ram: 3gb 
The task is too read 90,000 rows from Excel File.
Cant understand the problem.

```
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource$FakeZipEntry.<init>           
    (ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:120)at 
    org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.<init>(Zip
    InputStreamZipEntrySource.java:55)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:84)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:272)
    at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:39)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:218)
    at defg.jButton4ActionPerformed(defg.java:975)
    at defg.access$9(defg.java:942)
    at defg$9.actionPerformed(defg.java:539)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Open a command prompt and run `java -jar MyJarFile.jar`. Post any error messages that you get.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: Show your code, please

Comment: @CocoNess see the above quesn plzz